# Validate the JWT Bearer Token In Identity Server 4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have an Identity Server running based on IdentityServer 4, and I have an ASP.NET WebAPI built in ASP.Net Core Web API. I have a successfully login on the /connect/token endpoint of the identity server. I want to check the validity of JWT bearer token sent in the header of my API requests.

**This is the configuration in my startup API project :**

*In ConfigureServices :*

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
        {
            //base-address of my identityserver
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:5000/";

            //name of the API resource
            options.ApiName = "API_Resource_Name";
            });
```

*In Configure :*

```
 app.UseAuthentication();
```

**NB :** I've Added Authorize Annotation to my controller

Comment: Why do you want to check the validity of the token? That's what IdentityServer is for.

Comment: @GHDevOps I mean i want to configure the my API project to let identity server check the validity of access_token and authorize my controller if the access_token is valid.

Comment: If you have a dedicated server for IDS4 then you don't need to add Identity to your API. You need to configure your API to handle the JWT token that will be passed in from your request. I'll add my API startup below.

Comment: @GHDevOps Yes, Is exactly what i'm looking for. i'm to looking of how  can i configure my API to handle the JWT token that will be passed in from my request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add authentication and authorization to your API Startup.cs ConfigureServices:

```
            services.AddAuthentication("bearer")
            .AddJwtBearer("bearer", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = Configuration["Authority"];                    
                options.Events = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {

                        var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                        var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) && (path.StartsWithSegments("/chathub")))
                        {
                            context.Token = accessToken;
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnTokenValidated = context =>
                    {
                        var token = context.SecurityToken as JwtSecurityToken;
                        if (token != null)
                        {
                            ClaimsIdentity identity = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                            if (identity != null)
                            {
                                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", token.RawData));
                            }
                        }

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    NameClaimType = "name",
                    RoleClaimType = "role"
                };
            });
```

And then...

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("ApiScope", policy =>
            {
                policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                policy.RequireClaim("scope", "SignalR.API");
            });
        });
```

Inside Configure...

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```